# Composer issue on Symfony 2.7 app when deploying to AWS - Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services

I have been trying nearly all day to get a symfony app deployed on EB. Initally i had symfony 3.0 running, then downgraded to 2.7 as i thought it may help with versions

Anyways, trying to get 2.7 running just now and iam getting the following error in my logs-

```
 + PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
 + echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
 Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
 + composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
 Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - This package requires php >=5.5.9 but your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
  - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
  - symfony/symfony v3.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 3
  - symfony/symfony v3.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  - sensio/generator-bundle v3.0.0 requires symfony/console ~2.7|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
  - Installation request for sensio/generator-bundle v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/generator-bundle[v3.0.0].
    (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Anyone have any suggestions? even a very straight easy to follow tutorial on how to deploy a symfony app onto AWS, i have so far been following this but error error error... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html

thanks to any help in advance!?:)

Comment: try clearing the cache of composer with `php composer.phar clear-cache`

Comment: I shouldnt need to do that because the composer.phar is my git ignore as i was directed to do in the link i provided?! :/

Comment: The first error message is telling you that yur server is using php 5.4, symfony 3 requires 5.5.9.  Trying to switch between 3.0 and 2.x is going to cause all sorts of dependency issues.  Frankly you best bet would be to just start over with 2.7 or 2.8 and walk through the process.

Comment: Already working through that exact process, hopefull get this working! :'0